# How to convert the query result from multiple columns to two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm using Google Charts to draw pie chart. For drawing it, the two column format of data is necessary. The code for drawing google charts is not given here as it's the part of future implementation. For fetching the data from database I've written the following code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","XYZ","pqrs") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
    mysql_select_db("LMN", $con); 

    $sql  =" SELECT COUNT(*) 'carried_out', SUM(transaction_status = 'success') success, ";
    $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') inprocess, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') fail, ";
    $sql .=" SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') cancelled FROM user_transaction GROUP BY transaction_status";

    $sth = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    /*$result  = mysql_fetch_array($sth, MYSQL_ASSOC); 
    print_r($result); die;*/
    $rows = array();
    //flag is not needed
    $flag = true;
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'Transaction Category', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);
//print_r($table);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['user_transaction']); 
//print_r($temp);
    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['transaction_count']); 
    //print_r($temp);

    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    //print_r($rows);

}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

//print_r($table);

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;


    ?>
```

If I execute the above query I get the following result:

```
carried_out     success     inprocess   fail    cancelled
18  18  0   0   0
8   0   8   0   0
64  0   0   0   64
```

But I want the result into two columns named transactions_category and transaction_count. Can you help me what changes should I do the SQL query in order to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your query

```
SELECT 'Success' as transactionType, count(*) from user_transaction where transaction_status = 'success';
UNION
SELECT 'In Process' as transactionType, count(*) from user_transaction where transaction_status = 'inprocess'
UNION
SELECT 'Fail' as transactionType, count(*) from user_transaction where transaction_status = 'fail'
UNION
SELECT 'Cancelled' as transactionType, count(*) from user_transaction where transaction_status = 'Cancelled';
```

Uses the union operator to combine the result sets from multiple queries into a single result set.

Comment: I tried your query but it's giving errors. Can you give me the exact runnable code of a query? One more thing I noticed is you didn't mention the FROM table name anywhere in the query.

Comment: updated code with the from clause... it lints now but I don't have your table to test it against.